# What does (s.d.) stand for in literature cited section of a paper

Tags: abbreviations

I think *s.d.* is some reference to a date. I know that *n.d.* means "no date".

Here are the complete citations I encountered:

> Tennessee Wildlife Resources Agency. "Asian Carp in Tennessee Information and Images." (s.d.): tn.gov/twra/wildlife/fish/asian-carp.html. United States Geological Survey.
>
> "Are Asian Carp Dangerous?" U.S. Department of Interior (s.d.) usgs.gov/faqs/….

These citations are in a report by the Howard Baker Center.
My staff attorney says it may be Latin for *sine die* which means "without a date".

Comment: The Latin for ‘without’ is _sine_ – does that help?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the free dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sine+die), *s.d.* can be defined as:

> *s.d.* or *sine die* - without a day fixed  [literally:  without a day]

In the context of literature citation *s.d.* and *n.d.* have the same meaning.