# What does "s.d." mean here?

Tags: abbreviations

"32. Percy, Mahomet, ‘The Properties’.
33. Ibid., 1.1.26.
34. Ibid., 1.1.31, 49.
35. Ibid., 4.3.347.
36. Ibid., 4.6.37.
37. Ibid., 5.4.6.
38. Ibid., 5.13, s.d.
39. Ibid., 5.13. 3– 4.
40. Ibid., 5.13.129, s.d.
41. Ibid., 5.13. 9–14. "

The source: Jerry Brotton, *This Orient Isle- Elizabethan England and the Islamic World*, the footnotes of Chapter 11.

Comment: Probably an abbreviation of [***sine die***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sine-die).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does (s.d.) stand for in literature cited section of a paper](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/474595/what-does-s-d-stand-for-in-literature-cited-section-of-a-paper)

Comment: Thank you, Decapitated Soul, but this meaning doesn't seem to be fit in here; here are the other footnotes in the same place:32. Percy, Mahomet, ‘The Properties’.   33.  Ibid.,  1.1.26.   34. Ibid., 1.1.31, 49.   35. Ibid.,  4.3.347.   36. Ibid.,  4.6.37.   37. Ibid.,  5.4.6.   38. Ibid., 5.13, s.d.   39. Ibid.,  5.13. 3–  4.   40.  Ibid., 5.13.129, s.d.   41. Ibid.,  5.13. 9–14.

Comment: @Rosa1917 Please add information **to the question** if it's relevant. Not only is it easier to format, but it keeps everything in one place. Comments are ephemeral. You can [edit your question](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/543967/edit). I can't see why some *Ibid.* references get "s.d." and others don't, since presumably the entire publication has a date (or doesn't): I don't see why different parts of it might be different.

Comment: Thank you for the warning, Andrew Leach, I did so.

Answer (score 5):

I think "s.d." in this context stands for "stage direction." This is because each footnote refers to the Act, Scene, and Line numbers of William Percy's play "Mahomet and His Heaven." So, for example, footnote 37 reads "Ibid., 5.4.6." which I take to mean "Mahomet, Act 5, Scene 4, line 6". Therefore note 40, which reads "Ibid., 5.13.129, s.d.", I think means "Mahomet, Act 5, Scene 13, line 129, stage direction."

I base this on a similar note in James Morwood's translation of "Euripides: Medea & Other Plays", published through Oxford World's Classics (1998); the note on p. 181 to line 87 of Euripides' "Hippolytus" begins with s.d.; and it refers to an asterisk in the stage directions on p. 41 (the text of the play itself).

Comment: In support of your suggestion, MLA Style Center offers this comment on its page titled "[How do I quote stage directions?](https://style.mla.org/quoting-stage-directions/)": "To indicate that the quoted material is a stage direction, some scholars use the abbreviation _sd_ after the line number: (120sd). But in an essay that is not specialized in theater history, it would be better to avoid mystifying your readers with that technical detail."